# Sort function of two vector using make_pair in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I am using C++ to sort 2 vectors P and f by descending order of f. For example, I have

```
P    f
1000 3
0001 3
1100 2
1000 3
```

My expected output is
    P    f
    1000 3
    0001 3
    1000 3
    1100 2

That means if it is high value of f but orignal order (in P) is bigger then it must sort after. For my example, second and third have same f =3. But order of 0001 is 2 and order of 1000 is 3. So 1000 is sorted after 0001. I tried with this code but it is become

```
P    f
1000 3
1000 3
0001 3 
1100 2
```

How to modify it? Thanks

```
vector<vector <int> > P;  
std::vector<double> f;
P.resize(4);
 for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < P.size(); ++i)
{
  P[i].resize(4);
}
P[0][0]=1;
P[0][1]=0;
P[0][2]=0;
P[0][3]=0;

P[1][0]=0;
P[1][2]=0;
P[1][2]=0;
P[1][3]=1;

P[2][0]=1;
P[2][3]=1;
P[2][2]=0;
P[2][3]=0;

P[3][0]=1;
P[3][4]=0;
P[3][2]=0;
P[3][3]=0;
f=get_f(P);// Don't care --It will return 3 3 2 3
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
     cout<<P[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
vector< pair<double, vector<int> > > X; 
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        X.push_back(make_pair(f[i],P[i]));

////Sorting fitness descending order
stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend());
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  P[i]=X[i].second;
  f[i]=X[i].first;
}
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
     cout<<P[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you could have a look at [zip.iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)

Comment: `make_pair` really doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: Let see my update figure. What is happen in my code. Can you edit for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `std::stable_sort` to preserve relative order of *equivalent* elements:

```
std::stable_sort(X.rbegin(), X.rend(),
                [](const auto&lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Aan1Gb)

Comment: @user8430: Add comparison lambda to not sort according to vector.

Comment: Thank. But my expected output is 1000; 0001; 1000;1100

Comment: `f` was badly initialized, fixed. and to be compatible with C++11, replace `auto` by `std::pair<double, std::vector<int>`, (and for C++03, you have to turn the lambda in functor)

Comment: [question about your problem with const auto&](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071453/how-to-used-const-auto-in-c-11)